# Remove allfile option in JFileChosser Java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm using swings JFileChooser in program. I want it to filter files with `.txt`-extension and it is showing allfiles option also in window. I want to remove allfiles option, how can I do that?

This is my code:

```
fc1 = new JFileChooser();

fc1.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true); // Allow for multiple selections
fc1.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\"));
fc1.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".fls")
                    || f.isDirectory();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "*.fls";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, just by reading the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), I can see that there's a method called `setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean)`. Did you try that? It sounds like it's doing what you want.